# Error installing the build on device

Tags: iphone

I have prepared the build for an app.

The build is showing on itunes but is not being installed on device.

It shows the following error: "Couldn't register com.gmail.griffin.corporation.ltd with the bootstrap server."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "com.gmail.griffin.corporation.ltd"?

Comment: To solve the problem you can try this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383776/objective-c-getting-error-on-console-while-trying-to-display-app-on-ipad-devic

Answer (score 0):

ok, just stop all of your builds by pressing stop and selecting all of them, if that doesnt work, quit xcode, delete the app from your device, and then restart the device