# Objective-C : getting error on console while trying to display app on ipad device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, deployment

I am trying to display my iphone/Ipad app on my iPad but getting this error, I checked this app on device earlier but now its giving error on console.

```
**warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).**
```

**Couldn't register com.domainname.abcdef with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.

This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).**

My application working fine on Simulator  but giving this error on device provided that yesterday it was also working on device with same code.

I restarted Xcode , deleted build folder but no succes.

Comment: I hate to say it, but sometimes restarting your computer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz do as following...

Restart `iOS Simulator` and then `Reset contents and settings` and then delete `build` folder from directory path and then `clean all targets` after this run your application...

I am not sure about this but when i got this error I had done the same thing and solved this error..

Remove your device and connect it again.. and restart XCode and then try again..

Comment: from Reset contents and settings do you mean Clean ? clean with dependencies and precompiled headers?

Comment: Reset Contents and Settings is for iOS simulator not for device

Comment: If you are running with iOS simulator then go to menu and find iOS Simulator and click on Reset Contents and Settings

Comment: on simulator working its fine ... no error .... but for device its giving this error

Comment: had you deleted build folder?

Answer (score 2):

I just restarted the device and deleted the build folder and not its working ...

but I think it could working just by restarting the device ...

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode will surely resolve this error....

Comment: Did you delete the previous build from device and also Clean Target from Xcode,also empty cache...